# Python: How to capitalize the first column of a .txt file.

Tags: python, string, text, multiple-columns

I have a `.csv` formatted `.txt` file. I am deliberating over the best manner in which to `.capitalize` the text in the first column.

`.capitalize()` is a string method, so I considered the following; I would need to open the file, convert the data to a list of strings, capitalize the the required word and finally write the data back to file.

To achieve this, I did the following:

```
newGuestList = []
with open("guestList.txt","r+") as guestFile :
guestList = csv.reader(guestFile)
for guest in guestList :
    for guestInfo in guest :
        capitalisedName = guestInfo.capitalize()
        newGuestList.append(capitalisedName)
```

Which gives the output:
`[‘Peter’, ‘35’, ‘ spain’, ‘Caroline’, ‘37’, ‘france’, ‘Claire’,’32’, ‘ sweden’]`

The problem:

Firstly; in order to write this new list back to file, I will need to convert it to a string. I can achieve this using the `.join` method. However, how can I introduce a newline, `\n`, after every third word (the country) so that each guest has their own line in the text file?

Secondly; this method, of nested `for` `loops` etc. seems highly convoluted, is there a cleaner way?

My `.txt` file:
peter, 35, spain\n
caroline, 37, france\n
claire, 32, sweden\n

Comment: If the file already contains new lines. I would do it with 2 files. Read line from one, capitalize it and write it out to the other. (if very large files might want to read/write in batches of 100 or more lines). If you want capital letters, maybe do the countries too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to split the lines, since the first caracter of the first word is the first caracter of the line :

```
with open("lst.txt","r") as guestFile :
    lines=guestFile.readlines()
    newlines=[line.capitalize() for line in lines]
with open("lst.txt","w") as guestFile :
    guestFile.writelines(newlines)
```

Comment: I'd use `[line.capitalize() for line in lines]`, it's clearer and doesn't shadow the builtin `str`.

Comment: also you can remove `lines=guestFile.readlines()` and do `[line.capitalize() for line in guestFile]`

Comment: @B.M. Forgive me, I am new to programming, I do not understand this line of code `newlines=[line.capitalize() for line in lines]`. I have not come across this syntax before. `line` appears to be a keyword, although I cannot locate it in the docs.? I'm confused.

Comment: It's a  comprehension list. you can simply write : `newlines=[];for line in lines: newlines.append(line.capitalize())`, it does the same job.

Comment: Looks like I need to learn about comprehension lists next! Thank you very much B.M.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a CSV reader and writer and access the element you want to capitalize from the list.

```
import csv
import os

inp = open('a.txt', 'r')
out = open('b.txt', 'w')

reader = csv.reader(inp)
writer = csv.writer(out)

for row in reader:
    row[0] = row[0].capitalize()
    writer.writerow(row)

inp.close()
out.close()

os.rename('b.txt', 'a.txt') # if you want to keep the same name
```

Comment: os.rename won't work under Windows when a.txt already exists.